# How to highlight some text using html?

Tags: android

working perfect but
when i am highlight text using html then some text can not be view perfect(Hindi text).

android

```
String str="रिश्ते भले ही कम ही बनाओ लेकिन दिल से निभाओ,\n" +
                "क्योंकि आज कल इंसान अच्छाई के चक्कर में अच्छे खो देते है।";


//textview.setText(str);
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(String.format(colorfulltext(str))), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);      


// highlight text
public String colorfulltext(String text) {
    String[] colors = new String[]{"#fdc113", "#fdc113", "#fdc113","#fdc113", "#fdc113" ,"#fcfcfc", "#fcfcfc", "#fcfcfc", "#fcfcfc", "#fcfcfc", "#fcfcfc", "#fcfcfc", "#fcfcfc", "#fcfcfc","#fcfcfc","#fcfcfc","#fcfcfc","#fcfcfc"};

    StringBuilder finals = new StringBuilder();

    int size = colors.length;
    int k = 0;
    for (int item = 0; item < text.length(); item++) {
        if (k >= size) {
            k = 0;
        }
        finals.append("<font color='" + colors[k] + "'>" + text.charAt(item) + "</font>");
            k++;
    }
    return finals.toString();
}
```

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Wxd5.png)

Comment: Why not use SpnnableStringBuilder with ForegroundColorSpan?

Comment: because i have more then 500+ string...if you you have example plz share it

Answer (score 0):

Why do you convert a String to html to apply fontcolor for a static text??

You have to follow the following steps:

1. Create entries in Strings.xml for each text. For instance, रिश्ते 
   has a different color and needs to be a separate entry in
   strings.xml.
2. add this to a Util class:

   ```
   public static void addColoredPart(SpannableStringBuilder ssb,
                                  String word, int color,String... texts) {

   for(String text : texts) {
       if (word != null) {
           int idx1 = text.indexOf(word);
           if (idx1 == -1) {
               return;
           }
           int idx2 = idx1 + word.length();
           ssb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), idx1, idx2, 
           Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
       }
    }
   }
   ```
3. apply style the following way:

   ```
   String string1 = context.getString(R.string.String_id1)
   String string2 = context.getString(R.string.String_id2)
   SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
   spannableStringBuilder.append(string2)
   spannableStringBuilder.append(string2)
   SpannableUtil.addColoredPart(
                       spannableStringBuilder,
   spannableStringBuilder.toString(), color, string1, string2);
   ```

Comment: i have lot's of string and all string getting from database. text highlight function working proper but some text not show proper..please see attach screenshot.

Comment: When you say some, tell us what are they or say an example from screenshot

Comment: The color #cfcfc is almost white and #fdc113 is yellow..  everything is working perfect already

Comment: please check screenshot....when i am try Hindi text highlight at this time problem generate dear.    https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Wxd5.png

Comment: You are using characters to iterate and your characters are not english.. So can you print the character that comes in iteration and check if the characters are parsed as you expeced!!

Comment: I think your words are a combination of characters and श्ते is a combination of 4 characrers and thats y you find it printed in a weird format.. try encoding your characters with UTF-8 or find a correct encoding for your styled characters before rendering..